# The order in which diffeomorphisms should be applied

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I’m reading ‘**Bombay Lectures on Highest Weight Representations of Infinite Dimensional Lie Algebras**’ by Kac and Raina. And there is a following paragraph in the first chapter.

> The Lie algebra $\operatorname{Vect}(S^{1})$ can be considered as the Lie algebra of the group $G$ of orientation preserving diffeomorphisms of $S^{1}$. If $\zeta_{1}$, $\zeta_{2}$ are two elements of $G$ then their product is defined by composition:
> $$\zeta_{1}\cdot\zeta_{2} = \zeta_{1}\big(\zeta_{2}(z)\big)$$
> for each $z = \exp (i\theta)$ on $S^{1}$. If $f(z)$ is an element of the vector space of smooth complex-valued functions on $S^{1}$, then $\gamma\in G$ acts on $f(z)$ by
> $$\pi(\gamma) f(z) = f\big(\gamma^{-1}(z)\big).$$
> This clearly defines a representation of $G$.

Probably this is a notation subtlety I missed on Lie Groups representations, but I can’t see why $\pi$ is a representation, as it switches the order of multiples:
\begin{multline}
\forall\xi_{1},\xi_{2}\in G: \pi(\xi_{1}\cdot\xi_{2})f(z) = f\big((\xi_{1}\cdot\xi_{2})^{-1}(z)\big) = f\left(\left(\xi_{2}^{-1}\cdot\xi_{1}^{-1}\right)(z)\right) = \\ = f\left(\xi_{2}^{-1}\left(\xi_{1}^{-1}\left(z\right)\right)\right) = \pi(\xi_{2})f\left(\xi_{1}^{-1}(z)\right)= \big(\pi(\xi_{2})\cdot\pi(\xi_{1})\big)f(z)
\end{multline}
Therefore $\pi(\xi_{1}\cdot\xi_{2}) = \pi(\xi_{2})\cdot\pi(\xi_{1})$ so it kind of works like an ‘anti’-representation. However if we denote
\begin{equation}
(\zeta_{1}\cdot\zeta_{2})(z) = \zeta_{2}\big(\zeta_{1}(z)\big) 
\end{equation}
everything works as it should
\begin{multline}
\forall \xi_{1},\xi_{2}\in G : \pi(\xi_{1}\cdot\xi_{2})f(z) = f\big((\xi_{1}\cdot\xi_{2})^{-1}(z)\big) 
= f\left(\left(\xi_{2}^{-1}\cdot\xi_{1}^{-1}\right)(z)\right) = \\
= f\left(\xi_{1}^{-1}\left( \xi_{2}^{-1}(z)\right)\right)
= \pi(\xi_{1})f\left(\xi_{2}^{-1}(z)\right) = \left(\pi(\xi_{1})\cdot\pi(\xi_{2})\right)f(z)
\end{multline}
therefore $\pi(\xi_{1}\cdot\xi_{2}) = \pi(\xi_{1})\cdot\pi(\xi_{2})$.

I’m not sure if it is a typo as I saw similar  notation in other places and I do recall that a similar discussion was dedicated to the order of multiples in the case of regular representations for finite groups. But there it was more obvious. If $f:G\to \mathbb{C}$ we had three representations
\begin{gather}
\lambda_{g}f(h) = f(gh)\\
\rho_{g}f(h) = f\left(hg^{-1}\right)\\
\pi_{g}f(h) = f\left(ghg^{-1}\right)
\end{gather}
and it is straightforward why all of them are well-defined.

The more I think in which order should I multiply $\xi_{i}$, $\xi_{i}^{-1}$ and $\pi(\xi_{i})$ the more clueless I get. Could anyone clarify this concept, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing extra notation for the intermediate steps of the computation and worrying about the point evaluations at $z\in S^1$ separately might make things clearer.

Let $g:=\pi(\xi_2)f$. Applying the definition of the action, we obtain at each $z\in S^1$
$$\pi(\xi_1)g(z) = g(\xi_1^{-1}(z)).$$
On the other hand, by definition of the action we have at each point $w\in S^1$
$$g(w) = f(\xi_2^{-1}(w)).$$
Evaluating at $w=\xi_1^{-1}(z)$, we obtain
$$\pi(\xi_1)(\pi(\xi_2)f)(z) = \pi(\xi_1)g(z) = g(\xi_1^{-1}(z)) = f(\xi_2^{-1}(\xi_1^{-1}(z))),$$
so we see that the order gets flipped correctly.

You can also avoid the point evaluations altogether by thinking in terms of composition of functions, so the group product $\xi_1\cdot\xi_2$ is composition $\xi_1\circ\xi_2$ and the action is $\pi(\gamma)f = f\circ\gamma^{-1}$. Then the required computation takes the form
$$\pi(\xi_1\circ\xi_2)f = f\circ(\xi_1\circ\xi_2)^{-1} = f\circ\xi_2^{-1}\circ\xi_1^{-1} = (\pi(\xi_2)f)\circ \xi_1^{-1} = \pi(\xi_1)(\pi(\xi_2)f).$$

Comment: @Eero_Hakavuori Thanks! This totally makes sense now!!